# How do I set GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES and what do I set it to?

Tags: gnustep

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS in VirtualBox 4.2.6 on Windows 7. I am trying to build GNUstep Base from source as downloaded from the [official repository on GitHub](https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-base) instead of installing any part of GNUstep using APT (don't ask). When I entered `sudo make install` in Terminal I got

GNUmakefile:29:
   GNUmakefile:30: Unable to obtain GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES setting from gnustep-config!
   GNUmakefile:31: Perhaps gnustep-make is not properly installed,
   GNUmakefile:32: so gnustep-config is not in your PATH.
   GNUmakefile:33:
   GNUmakefile:34: Your PATH is currently /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
   GNUmakefile:35:
   GNUmakefile:40: *** You need to set GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES before compiling!  Stop.

Heh (sarcasm). My `PATH` variable is actually set to `/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/GNUstep/System/Tools:/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Makefiles`. What is going on here?

Comment: Did you install gnustep-make https://github.com/gnustep/gnustep-make ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did. What do I need to set the variable to? Was GNUstep Make supposed to set it?

Comment: You need to source /the/path/to/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh first. Mine's in /usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh Then you can verify the env variables if they were set properly using command like set | grep GNUSTEP

Answer (score 3):

You need to source the /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh script that sets all the required `GNUSTEP_*` variables:

```
$ . /usr/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh         # or
$ . /usr/local/share/GNUstep/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
$ make
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to source `GNUstep.sh` as root to allow the installation to work.

```
$ sudo su
# . /usr/GNUstep/System/Library/Makefiles/GNUstep.sh
# export GNUSTEP_SYSTEM_LIBRARY=/usr/GNUstep/System/Library/
# export PATH=$PATH:/user/GNUstep/System/Tools/
# ./configure
# make
# make install
```